# How to pass the value of Html.Checkbox to the Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.checkbox

Basically what the title says:

This must happen without having a submit button.
This is what I got, but have no idea how to go further:

**View**

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateReleaseState", "Articles", new{reference=Model.Reference, CheckboxState=true})) {%>
                    <%=Html.CheckBox("CheckboxState", Model.DoNotCheckReleaseState)%> Do not check release state
</div>
```

**Action**

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult UpdateReleaseState(Guid reference, bool CheckboxState)
 {
     throw new NotImplemtedException();
 }
```

In my view I am trying to pass the value of the Checkbox, but dont know what to provide as parameter.Currently it is check=true

Comment: The breakpoint is on the throw, but it never gets hit when I check the Checkbox

Answer (score 1):

In your `CheckBox` method you have specified its name - `CheckboxState`. Therefore after the form is posted, request will contain part `CheckboxState=true` or `CheckboxState=false`. Now all you need to do is to specify the same name for the action parameter (case insensitive):

```
public ActionResult UpdateReleaseState(Guid reference, bool checkboxState)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your signature to this:

```
public ActionResult UpdateReleaseState(Guid reference, bool CheckboxState)
```

MVC uses names to bind values. And one other note, **casing is important,** just because it's more readable the interpretable. But as discovered by Andrei, it's not relevant to it working.

Comment: About case - is it? As far as I know it is not.

Comment: @Andrei, I remember having an issue with casing a while back. It could be that I modified something else along the way that fixed it too, but I guess since then I've always ensured that the casing is correct. In short, MVC uses `Reflection` to find the properties to bind to, and unless otherwise specified, it's case-sensitive.

Comment: I very much doubt that your issue was cause by casing. You can try it yourself with a basic example: send a post request with `ID` and receive it in action as `id`. Just tried that to be absolutely sure, everything worked as expected. This is not the say that you rule to about casing is a bad one - it is quite useful I think.

Comment: @Andrei, fantastic discovery and proof, thanks! I learned something today. I've updated my answer, and +1 for too friend as your answer is just as correct.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, me too learned something.But still it doesn't seem to post, when checking it still does not got to the action.How to I pass the control value.Currently:  <% using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateReleaseState", "Articles", new { reference = Model.Reference}))%>
                        <%=Html.CheckBox("checkboxSapState", Model.DoNotCheckReleaseState)%> Do not check release state

Comment: @user1702369, and what's the action signature look like?

Comment: public ActionResult UpdateReleaseState(Guid reference, bool checkboxSapState)

Comment: @user, according to you the name of the check box is checkBoxState, not checkboxSapState. The parameter name must be the same as the control name.

Comment: Arggg all the typo's.Look at my initial question.I up dated how I'm calling it currently